# How to convert an integer to a list of bits?

Tags: python

I'm trying to represent an integer as a list of bits and left pad it to 8 bits **only if the integer is < 128**:

```
Example input: 0x15
Desired output: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I do it in the following way:

```
input = 0x15
output = deque([int(i) for i in list(bin(input))[2:]])
while len(output) != 8:
    output.appendleft(0)
```

I would like to convert any integer to a binary-list. Pad to 8 only if the number requires less than 8 bits to represent.

```
Another Example input: 0x715
Desired output: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

How can I do this both for numbers less then 8 bits and also for larger ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
number = 0x15

output = [int(x) for x in '{:08b}'.format(number)]
```

`'{:08b}'.format(number)` represents your `number` in `binary` format with 0 padding to 8 digits, then using list comprehension to create a list of bits.

Alternatively, you can use `map` function:

```
output = map(int, '{:08b}'.format(0x15))
```

---

If you want to use a variable number of bits, here is one way:

```
width = 8  # 8bit width
output = [int(x) for x in '{:0{size}b}'.format(0x15, size=width)]
output = map(int, '{:0{size}b}'.format(0x15, size=width))
```

***For Python 3***, wrap the `map(...)` call with `list()` (`map` returned a list in Python 2 but returns an iterator in 3).

Answer (score 15):

#### For a fixed size of 8 bits:

```
num = 0x15
out = [1 if num & (1 << (7-n)) else 0 for n in range(8)]
```

The `(1 << (7-n))` creates a single bit mask for a given position, and then bitwise `&` tests to see if that bit is set in the number. Having `n` work through 0 to 7 results in all 8 bits in the byte being tested in order.

#### For arbitrarily sized numbers:

```
import math
num = 0x715
bits = int(max(8, math.log(num, 2)+1))
out = [1 if num & (1 << (bits-1-n)) else 0 for n in range(bits)]
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but after the edit you'll need to deal with numbers bigger than 8 bits too.

Comment: for little-endian bit lists you can just use `[n & 1 << b and 1 for b in range(bitlength)]`

Comment: The shift and masking can be done so to bring the desired bit to the rightmost position, thus skipping the check `1 if that_bit_over_there_is_one else 0`. `[(num >> shift) & 0x01 for shift in range(7, -1, -1)]`

Comment: This solution also handles negative numbers using [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_from_two's_complement_representation) representation. _However_, with 2C counting the valid domain is `[-128,127]` while standard binary counting [on non-negative numbers] is valid on `[0, 255]`.

Comment: It doesn't work for 0

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> [int(n) for n in bin(0x15)[2:].zfill(8)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

The slice `[2:]` is to remove `0b` prefix, `zfill(8)` is to pad zeros on the left.

Answer (score 5):

## Solution

Works for any number of bits, faster than the [accepted
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30971156/4682839) and the [current
highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30971101/4682839):

```py
num = 0xAAAA
bit_list = [(num >> shift_ind) & 1
             for shift_ind in range(num.bit_length())] # little endian
bit_list.reverse() # big endian
```

```py
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

## Timings

```py
from timeit import timeit

def accepted_answer(number):
    output = [int(x) for x in '{:08b}'.format(number)]

    return output

def highest_voted_answer(num):
    out = [1 if num & (1 << (7-n)) else 0 for n in range(8)]

    return out

def this_answer(num):
    bit_list = [(num >> shift_ind) & 1
                for shift_ind in range(num.bit_length())] # little endian
    bit_list.reverse() # big endian

    return bit_list

NUM = 0x15
ITERATIONS = int(1e7)

print(timeit(lambda: accepted_answer(NUM), number=ITERATIONS))
print(timeit(lambda: highest_voted_answer(NUM), number=ITERATIONS))
print(timeit(lambda: this_answer(NUM), number=ITERATIONS))
```

```py
9.884788331000891
9.262861715000327
6.484631327999523
```

Comment: Endianess is about byte-order not bit-order -> bit order would be the same.
You have to reverse the bit list to match bit #0 to list index #0, but this is not about endianess.

0xF102
-> F1, 02 -> 0b1111 0001 0000 0010 (big-endian)
-> 02, F1 -> 0b0000 0010 1111 0001 (little-endian)

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to do this with format strings

```
>>> "{:08b}".format(0x15)
'00010101'
>>> "{:08b}".format(0x151)
'101010001'
>>> "{:08b}".format(0x1511)
'1010100010001'
```

to convert to a list

```
>>> [1 if x=='1' else 0 for x in "{:08b}".format(0x15)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> [1 if x=='1' else 0 for x in "{:08b}".format(0x1511)]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

It's likely to be faster using bit twiddling as in @Amber's answer, but then you'll have to check for special cases and end up with quite a bit of code. If utmost performance isn't required, it's safer to build on what you know already works

Comment: You can convert a string to a list using `list(string)` so `map(int, list("{:08b}".format(n))` works

Comment: @Raniz, but `map` doesn't return a `list` in Python3, so I prefer to use a list comprehension

Comment: right, but you could then just do `[int(x) for x in ... ]`

Comment: @RyanHaining, forgive my premature optimisation, but `int(x)` is much slower than `x=='1'`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy .. Thanks for the added information about map+Py3, and int(x) being slower than x==1.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(number, np.dtype('B')))
```

Comment: Can someone check the timings of this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the number x steps to the right and then make a bitwise and the result with 1 to get the bit at position `x`, do this with list-comprehension and you get your list. If you need to support negative numbers we may need to add a leading zero to the list to ensure that positive numbers doesn't start with a 1:

```
import math

def bits(n):
    # The number of bits we need to represent the number
    num_bits = max(8, int(math.log(abs(n), 2)) + 1)
    # The bit representation of the number
    bits = [ (n >> i) & 1 for i in range(num_bits) ]
    bits.reverse()
    # Do we need a leading zero?
    if n < 0 or bits[0] == 0:
        return bits
    return [0] + bits

# Examples
for n in (-0x15, 0x15, 128, 255, 256, -256):
    print("{: 4} = {}".format(n, bits(n)))
```

> ```
>  -21 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
>   21 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>  128 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>  255 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>  256 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> -256 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import ceil
input = 0x15
bin_string = bin(input)[2:]
binary = map(int,bin_string.zfill(int(ceil(len(bin_string)/8.0)*8)))
print(binary)
```

This will round to nearest multiple of 8 , if u want to round to multiple of 8 only if <128, use a simple if else statement and remove `zfill` in else

Output for 0x15:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Output for 0x715:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

If you only want to add zeros if less than 128, use this:

```
input = 0x715
bin_string = bin(input)[2:]
num_bits = (8 if input < 128 else 0)
binary = map(int,bin_string.zfill(num_bits))
print(binary)
```

Ouput for 0x15:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Output for 0x715:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use bitmasks far less than I used to, but when I do use them I often have the need to decompose a value into its parts

```
def get_Bits(number):
i = 1
list_of_hex = []
while (i <= number):
    if ((number & i) > 0):
        bitRepresentation = hex(i)
        list_of_hex.append(bitRepresentation)
        
    i = i*2

return list_of_hex
```

you can change the (hex) function to (bin) if you need the binary decomposition