# Python convert int to list of 1s and 0s?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I convert an int to list of 1s and 0s in python? This is an INT, not a string, not binary string.  Google keeps returning the wrong examples.

If theState=255, Result should be [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], a list of 1s and 0s.  I did the following but is there a better or more elegant way to do this?

```
theState=255
theState=bin(theState)[2:]
theState=[int(theDigit) for theDigit in str(theState)]
print('{}'.format(theState))
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: I'll add an answer using pure math later !

Comment: @Programmer Please don't. This site is for programming, not math.

Comment: @TylerH Umm … I think you got this wrong ! With pure math I meant that I won't be using `bin()` !

Comment: @Programmer Ah, well unfortunately answering still isn't the best case here since the question is off-topic.

Comment: *"is there a better or more elegant way?"* - Well, `print('{}'.format(theState)) == print(theState)`... Anyway, does this answer your question? [How do I convert an integer to a list of bits in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971079/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-a-list-of-bits-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic is as good as it's going to get, but you can still make it a little cleaner. Try this:

```
def convert_bin(num):
    return [int(bit) for bit in bin(num)[2:]]


print(convert_bin(255))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop and the modulo operator:

```py
def number_to_binary(number=255):
    result = []
    while number > 0:
        remainder = number % 2
        result.insert(0, remainder) # prepend the remainder to the list
        number //= 2
    return result

print(number_to_binary(255))
```

The formula I got from [indepth.dev](https://indepth.dev/posts/1019/the-simple-math-behind-decimal-binary-conversion-algorithms).