# Code that should transform words into binary doesn't work in python 3.10

Tags: python, binary

I know that there are certain built-in functions that do this but for fun, I wrote a code for it. Where is the mistake in this code?

For example the expected outcome for 'abc' is:

`[[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]]`

```
strlist = []
strinput = input("Enter a string only non capital letters to convert to binary: ")
lenstr = len(strinput)
a = lenstr-1
while a >= 0:
    listx = []
    if strinput[a] == 'a':
        x = 97
    elif strinput[a] == 'b':
        x = 98
    elif strinput[a] == 'c':
        x = 99
    i = 8
    while i>=0:
        if 2**i > x >= 2**(i-1):
            listx.append(1)
            x -= 2**(i-1)
        else:
           listx.append(0)
        i -= 1
    listx.pop(len(listx)-1)
    strlist.append(listx)
    a -= 1
print(strlist)
```

Comment: You're processing the string backwards.

Comment: Your conversion to binary works fine. You're just appending to `strlist` in reverse order.

Comment: Irrelevant, but you can streamline your code by changing the while loop to `for char in strinput: x = ord(char) <then the rest>`

Comment: You can also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971079/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-a-list-of-bits) on how to convert an integer to a list of bits.

Answer (score 0):

Made minor changes to get it working chars other than just 'abc'. And use `ord` for ascii code

```
strlist = []
strinput = input("Enter a string only non capital letters to convert to binary: ")
lenstr = len(strinput)
a = lenstr-1
for c in strinput:
    listx = []
    x = ord(c)
    i = 8
    while i >= 0:
        if 2**i > x >= 2**(i-1):
            listx.append(1)
            x -= 2**(i-1)
        else:
           listx.append(0)
        i -= 1
    listx.pop(len(listx)-1)
    strlist.append(listx)
    a -= 1
print(strlist)
```